# center an input element in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm using a flex container to place a button so that it abuts an input on its right border. I can't get the input to be horizontally centered. How to center it, without eliminating the `display: flex`?

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div>Enter the search term</div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <input id="abc" />
      <button id="search" name="search" type="submit">go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wpd3b0kt/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `justify-content:` to the CSS:

```
 .flexContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
  }
```

[**fiddle update**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/wpd3b0kt/2/)